# JavaScript character direction delay

Tags: javascript, animation, html5

I am developing a top down game and I'm having trouble with a delay in switching from one character walk direction to another, particularly if the previous direction key is still being pressed by the user.

Take the following user interaction:

- User presses up arrow;
- User presses right arrow (up arrow is still pressed);
- User releases up arrow (right arrow is still pressed).

The problem I am experiencing is that there is a delay in the character switching from the "walk up" movement to the "walk right" movement.

```
requestId: 0,
settimeoutID: 0,
counter: 0,

move: function(keyCode) {
  var _this = this;
  // Frame per seconds
  var fps = 60;

  if (this.requestId === 0) {
    (function animationLoop() {
      // Control the timing of an animation with requestAnimationFrame
      _this.settimeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
        _this.render();
        _this.requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop, _this.move);
      }, 1000 / fps);
    })();
  }
},

changeAnim: function() {
  if (this.counter % 10 === 0) {
    if (this.currentFrame > 1) {
      this.currentFrame = 0;
    } else {
      this.currentFrame++;
    }
  }
},

render: function() {
  // Add some drawing
  this.counter++;

  if (keyCode === config.PLAYER_DOWN) {
    this.action = 'Front';
    this.newPos.y += 1;
  } else if (keyCode === config.PLAYER_UP) {
    this.action = 'Back';
    this.newPos.y -= 1;
  }

  if (keyCode === config.PLAYER_RIGHT) {
    this.action = 'Right';
    this.newPos.x += 1;
  } else if (keyCode === config.PLAYER_LEFT) {
    this.action = 'Left';
    this.newPos.x -= 1;
  }
  this.changeAnim();
  // Draw player logic
  this.drawPlayer.reDraw(this.playerSprite[1].Walk[this.action][this.currentFrame], this.newPos);
},

onKeyUp: function() {
  // Cancel the animation request
  if (this.requestId) {
    clearTimeout(this.settimeoutID);
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.requestId);
  }
  // Allow a new request to be called
  this.requestId    = 0;
  this.counter      = 0;
  this.currentFrame = 0;
  this.drawPlayer.reDraw(this.playerSprite[1].Walk[this.action][this.currentFrame], this.newPos);
}
```

Note: The function move gets called every time a new key is being pressed.

Comment: You sure this has nothing to do with the standard repeat delay from the OS? When you press down a key it stops before it starts repeating itself.

Comment: I do not think that this has anything to do with the OS, as when I add a console.log() in the render function to check the keyCode and reproduce this exact same user interaction, I can see that 'right arrow' (output of keyCode) gets called once, following by a 'up arrow' and then a bunch of 'right arrow' input. I'm unsure how to avoid this 'up arrow' to get called when changing direction.

Comment: mmh... Looking at some information about this delay, it seems that you are right about it :( Would you know any way around it? :/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging your code for you. Could you condense this to a minimal test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As provided in the comments, if this is an issue of repeat delay then all you have to do is simply change your code to more of a state kind of process.

It might be a bit more code but its how you get things running

It could look like so :

```
   //variables
   var up = false;
   var down = false;
   var left = false;
   var right = false;

    //in your update

   if (keyCode === config.PLAYER_DOWN) {
    down = true;
  } else if (keyCode === config.PLAYER_UP) {
    up = true;
  }

  if (keyCode === config.PLAYER_RIGHT) {
    left = true;
  } else if (keyCode === config.PLAYER_LEFT) {
    right = true;
  }


  if(left == true)
  {
     this.action = 'Left';
     this.changeAnim();
     this.newPos.x -= 1;
  }
 else if(right == true)
 {
     this.action = 'Right';
     this.changeAnim();
     this.newPos.x += 1;
 }
//etc
```

It might look the same but unlike your key presses booleans are checked constantly without any delay. You're basically turning on and off by ONE key press.

This is an extremely simple way of doing it. And it should suffice. If you need something more complex simply look up how movement is handled in general.

( don't forget to set the variables to false on key up );

Comment: I've tried out your solution and it still doesn't work properly. I do not have an update function, but only start a requestAnimationFrame when retrieving an user input. This request gets removed on key up. I am new to 'setTimeout' / 'requestAnimationFrame' concepts. I might be doing something terribly wrong here :/

Comment: I've noticed you're only calling  **this.changeAnim();** when a key is pressed, shouldn't you just do that at the end anyway, outside the if/else clauses? So instead of 4 individual calls depending on key presses you just put **this.changeAnim();** at the end?
  
Btw the setTimeout is basically your update. You can add more functions between there if you need those to be called every frame as well.

Still looking at your code though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sidar, for your feedback (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/70458/22406). It has been a while since I've created character movement and I think I've lost the basics. I was creating an 'update' function only when the user was pressing down a key. This function was getting remove straight after the user has release a key.
The issue was then linked the this way of updating the movement. 
I've managed to make it work this way:

```
upPressed: 0,
downPressed: 0,
leftPressed: 0,
rightPressed: 0,
currentFrame: 0,

// Only called once
update: function() {
  var _this = this;

  (function animationLoop() {
    // Control the timing of an animation with requestAnimationFrame
    setTimeout(function() {
      _this.render();
      requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop, _this.update);
    }, 1000 / config.FPS);
  })();
},

// Call on press
onKeyDown: function(keyCode) {
  if (keyCode == config.PLAYER_UP)
    this.upPressed = 1;
  if (keyCode == config.PLAYER_DOWN)
    this.downPressed = 1;
  if (keyCode == config.PLAYER_LEFT)
    this.leftPressed = 1;
  if (keyCode == config.PLAYER_RIGHT)
    this.rightPressed = 1;
},

// Call on release
onKeyUp: function(keyCode) {
  if (keyCode == config.PLAYER_UP)
    this.upPressed = 0;
  if (keyCode == config.PLAYER_DOWN)
    this.downPressed = 0;
  if (keyCode == config.PLAYER_LEFT)
    this.leftPressed = 0;
  if (keyCode == config.PLAYER_RIGHT)
    this.rightPressed = 0;
},

changeAnim: function() {
  if (this.counter % 10 === 0) {
    if (this.currentFrame > 1) {
      this.currentFrame = 0;
    } else {
      this.currentFrame++;
    }
  }
},

render: function() {
  if (this.upPressed == 1) {
    this.action = 'Back';
    this.newPos.y -= 1;
  }
  else if (this.downPressed == 1) {
    this.action = 'Front';
    this.newPos.y += 1;
  }
  else if (this.rightPressed == 1) {
    this.action = 'Right';
    this.newPos.x += 1;
  }
  else if (this.leftPressed == 1) {
    this.action = 'Left';
    this.newPos.x -= 1;
  }

  if (this.upPressed == 1 || this.downPressed == 1 ||
    this.rightPressed == 1 || this.leftPressed == 1) {
    this.counter++;
    this.changeAnim(); 
    // Redraw the background
    mediator.call(mediatorEvent.REDRAW_PLAYERS);  
    // Draw user input on the map
    this.drawPlayer.reDraw(this.playerSprite[1].Walk[this.action][this.currentFrame], this.newPos);
  }
}
```